# I would like to record playing the piano for ABRSM exams. In the past, I have set up the iPad on a stand. How can I get better recordings?

Tags: piano, homerecording

In the past I have recorded for ABRSM piano exams on a digital piano on my iPad. I would like to know what I could do to improve the sound quality in digital recordings in the future. Could you please help with suggestions for sound quality improvement? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but as worded it's hard to tell whether it's a request for product recommendation [which is off-topic] or one for 'how to record piano?' which is far too broad to answer in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Welcome! Please read about [the topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [how to get objective answers](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and then use the edit button to explain some more. One easy (and useless) answer would be "use something better than an iPad." But assuming that you want to keep using the iPad, there are some suggestions like: use an app that doesn't apply any compression or noise filtering, make sure the mic is unobstructed (or use an external mic), and experiment with placement.

Comment: Try different positions of the iPad's micro using a suitable tripod. // See links for comb filter effect in https://music.stackexchange.com/tags/microphones/info . // As a last resort use an external mic with the required adapters for the iPad ... while the comb effect will still effect you.

Comment: Please update the question to include:  What type of piano (upright, grand)? What location (size of room and type of surfaces)?  What other equipment do you have at your disposal? Are there minimum or recommended standards set by ABRSM for the recordings?  (N.B.: Many here will not know what ABRSM is.)

Comment: Unless someone listening to the exams has complained, I’d suggest spending your time practicing and don’t worry about recording quality for the exams. If you want to be able to make high quality recording of yourself as a way to make money as a pianist, that’s a different question. You might search YouTube or just the web on how to record piano effectively.

Comment: This presumably is for *performance* exams, which require a continuous video of 4 pieces. That means the video needs to be showing the player and hands. You'd need a remote mic, and a decent piano mic is expensive!

Comment: By the way, I missed the phrase "on a digital piano." You don't mean that you're using a piano app *on* the iPad, do you? If you mean that you're playing an actual physical digital piano, then of course it complicates the question of "sound" even more: use a different patch? external speakers? a different piano? an actual acoustic piano?

Comment: The simplest way to improve the recording quality is to record line out instead of going through speakers and mic. iPad doesn't have a line input so you need an audio interface to do that.